# React-testing-library with Ionic v5 (react) and react-hook-form- change events do not fire

Tags: ionic-framework, react-testing-library, ionic-react

I am trying to test a component rendered with `Controller` from `react-hook-form` with `react-testing-library`

```
          <Controller
            render={({ onChange, onBlur, value }) => (
              <IonInput
                onIonChange={onChange}
                onIonBlur={onBlur}
                value={value}
                type="text"
                data-testid="firstname-field"
              />
            )}
            name="firstName"
            control={control}
            defaultValue={firstName}
          />
```

Default values are as expected when I render the component with a some mock data.  However, when I go about changing values, it seems the events are not firing.  From [this](https://ionicframework.com/blog/testing-ionic-react-apps-with-jest-and-react-testing-library/) blog post it looks like ionic exports a set of test utils to handle ionic's custom events.  After setting that up in my `setupTests.ts` I'm attempting to use both the ionFireEvent and the fireEvent from RTU, neither of which reflect changes in the component when I use `debug()`.  I've set it up so I can use both `fireEvent` and `ionFireEvent` to test:

```
import { render, screen, wait, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import { ionFireEvent } from "@ionic/react-test-utils";
```

```js
  // using RTL fireEvent - no change
  it("fires change event on firstname", () => {
    const { baseElement } = renderGolferContext(mockGolfer);
    const firstNameField = screen.getByTestId("firstname-field") as HTMLInputElement;
    fireEvent.change(firstNameField, { target: { detail: { value: "Jill" } } });
    expect(firstNameField.value).toBe("Jill");
  });

  // using IRTL ionFireEvent/ionChange - no change
  it("fires change event on firstname", () => {
    const { baseElement } = renderGolferContext(mockGolfer);
    const firstNameField = screen.getByTestId("firstname-field") as HTMLInputElement;
    ionFireEvent.ionChange(firstNameField, "Jill");
    expect(firstNameField.value).toBe("Jill");
  });    
    screen.debug(baseElement);
```

I've also tried moving the data-testid property to the controller rather than the `IonInput` suggested [here](https://dev.to/wendyperalta/comment/12boh), with the result being the same: no event is fired.

Here are the versions I'm using:

```
Using Ionic 5.1.1
@ionic/react-test-utils 0.0.3
jest  24.9
@testing-library/react 9.5
@testing-library/dom 6.16
```

[Here is a repo](https://github.com/tx-tim/my-cap-app/tree/master) I've created to demonstrate.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: do you have a small project somewhere?

Comment: @AaronSaunders Edited my question to include a link to the repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line appears to be incorrect...

`expect(firstNameField.value).toBe("Jill");`

It should be looking at `detail.value` since that is what you set

`expect((firstNameField as any).detail.value).toBe("Jill");`

this is my test,

```
describe("RTL fireEvent on ion-input", () => {
  it("change on firstname", () => {
    const { baseElement, getByTestId } = render(<IonicHookForm />);
    const firstNameField = screen.getByTestId(
      "firstname-field"
    ) as HTMLInputElement;
    fireEvent.change(firstNameField, {
      target: { detail: { value: "Princess" } },
    });
    expect((firstNameField as any).detail.value).toEqual("Princess");
  });
});
```